# How do I put limitations on how far a jQuery event can go?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $left = $('#scroll-left');
        var $right = $('#scroll-right');
        var position = $('#article_body').css('left');
        if (position <= '-450px') {
            $left.click(function() {
                $('#article_body').animate({
                    left: '+=450px'
                }, '1000');
            });
        } else if (position >= '-4500px') {
            $right.click(function() {
                $('#article_body').animate({
                    left: '-=450px'
                }, '1000');
            });
        }

 });
```

I made a horizontally scrolling page by setting the CSS left property on my containing div. What I want it to do is only move in between the interval of 0px and -4500px. So if I click left and it's at 0px, it will only move right, or if it's at -4500px and I click right, it will only move left.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the check *inside* the handlers, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#scroll-left').click(function() {
    if ($('#article_body').css('left') <= '-450px') {
      $('#article_body').animate({ left: '+=450px' }, '1000');
    }
  });
  $('#scroll-right').click(function() {
    if ($('#article_body').css('left') >= '-4500px') {
      $('#article_body').animate({ left: '-=450px' }, '1000');
    }
  });
});
```

Currently you're checking the position *when the DOM loads*, rather than *when the button is clicked*.  Instead you need to do the reverse, and check when the button is clicked...like above.  If it's scrolled too far in the direction you're checking (the `if` check fails), the click will just have no effect.

Comment: Thanks! This works except for some reason when I get to -1350px the function won't go any further. Any idea why?

Comment: @JJMalina - It's a string comparison, I think you want to compare `.position().left` here instead of `.css('left')`, and compare to integers e.g. `-450` not `'-450px'`, let me know if you have any issues after that.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a diagram of the interaction you desire, like a swimlane or something, that would be helpful.

Comment: Because what you are asking is not making much sense to this reader, and apparently to others as well.

Comment: I wasn't the one asking ;) but....I didn't think it was that complicated from the description either.  If it's all the way right, clicking "scroll right" shouldn't scroll any further...same with the left side.